# Failed to start gunicorn.service: Unit gunicorn.service not found

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

*I am trying to deploy a basic application to `Amazon EC2` using `Django`, `Gunicorn`, and `Nginx`. I have the app `git clone`'d into my `AWS` `Ubuntu` instance and am running `Django 1.10`.*

***I am able to run my app using `Gunicorn` with the following command...***

`gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 blackspruceherbals.wsgi:application`

***I am running into trouble though when I try to create a upstart file for `Gunicorn`. The file path is as follows...***

`/etc/init/gunicorn.conf`

***and the upstart code looks like this...***

```
description "Gunicorn application server handling black spruce herbals"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]
respawn
setuid ubuntu
setgid www-data
chdir /home/ubuntu/websitename/
exec bsh_env/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/websitename/websitename.sock websitename.wsgi:application
```

***When I run...***

`sudo service gunicorn start`

***I get the following error...***

`Failed to start gunicorn.service: Unit gunicorn.service not found.`

*What gives?  I have scoured the internet looking for an answer, but have found nothing. Can you see something obvious I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.*

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: 16.04 @AntonisChristofides

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Adding to [Antonis Christofides](https://stackoverflow.com/users/662345/antonis-christofides) answer:

**1) Open and create systemd service file:**

```
$ sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service
```

**2) Write the following content to the file:**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=name_of_user    
Group=name_of_user   
WorkingDirectory=/home/name_of_user/myproject
ExecStart=/home/name_of_user/myproject/virtualenv_directory/bin/gunicorn -- 
access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/name_of_user/myproject/myproject.sock myproject.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**3) Starting the service:**

```
$ sudo systemctl start gunicorn
```

**4) Enabling the service:**

```
$ sudo systemctl enable gunicorn
```

**5) Check the status of the process:**

```
$ sudo systemctl status gunicorn
```

For more visit [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Thanks. :)

Comment: I have exactly done this. But when I run `sudo systemctl start gunicorn` it says- `Failed to start gunicorn.service: Unit gunicorn.service not found.` What could be possible

Comment: @ReemaParakh I edit my answer changing this `ExecStart=/home/name_of_user/virtualenv_directory` to `ExecStart=/home/name_of_user/myproject/virtualenv_directory`

Comment: You need to find your virtualenv directory whoes subdirectories will be bin, local, lib etc and then replace `virtualenv_directory` with that directory.

Comment: It helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

Since Ubuntu 15.04 `upstart` has been replaced by `systemd`. You need to create a file `/etc/systemd/gunicorn.service`, which has a different syntax than the `upstart` file. The [FAQ](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd_FAQ#How_can_I_make_a_script_start_during_the_boot_process.3F) can get you started, and the reference is `man systemd.service`.