# No .sock file is being created by my gunicorn service

Tags: django, nginx, centos, gunicorn

I have the following problem while hosting my website. I configured all the things .conf files here:

gunicorn.service

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target
[Service]
User=user
Group=nginx
WorkingDirectory=/root/myproject
ExecStart=/root/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind 
unix:/root/myproject/myproject.sock myproject.wsgi:application
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and my nginx.conf

```
    server {
    listen 80;
server_name agros.uz www.agros.uz;

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

location /static/ {
       root /root/myproject/;
}

location / {
   proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       proxy_pass http://unix:/root/myproject/myproject.sock;
    }
}
```

However I am having the following error

```
unix:/root/myproject/myproject.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 37.9.113.208, server: agros.uz, request: "GET /uz/insurance?type=physical&page=2&page=7&page=6&page=8&page=4 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/root/myproject/myproject.sock:/uz/insurance?type=physical&page=2&page=7&page=6&page=8&page=4", host: "agros.uz"
```

When I access the domain this error happens `502 Bad Gateway` error

and the .sock file is not being created in `/root/myproject/myproject.sock` as it mentioned in my `gunicorn.service` file.

Comment: Is the gunicorn service definitely starting? What do the logs say?

Comment: the log says `unix:/root/myproject/myproject.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 37.9.113.208, server: agros.uz, .....`

Comment: No that's the nginx log. What about the gunicorn log, and the systemd log? Do they show gunicorn actually starting?

Comment: here the error `connect() to unix:/root/myproject/myproject.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 185.163.26.164, server: agros.uz, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/root/myproject/myproject.sock:/", host: "agros.uz"`

Comment: Simply run `gunicorn myproject.wsgi:application` to check if gunicorn is running successfully. Then check the directory where the .sock file is created and verify it with your gunicorn.service file.

Comment: follow what @Rakib said. if it's not there you should probably give the appropriate permissions to the folder where your socket gets created.

Comment: Try to change the `Group` in gunicorn to user.

Comment: I had faced the same problem before and I did fixed it but I don't remember how ... Here check my answer on this question and configure your gunicorn file as mentioned : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40711747/failed-to-start-gunicorn-service-unit-gunicorn-service-not-found/52912818#52912818

Comment: The problem is definitely not with the nginx...

Comment: you could probably also have `sudo apt-get install gunicorn` and `pip3 install gunicorn`. check this. If this is the reason first remove both and install  gunicorn with pip and also check your virtualenv/bin folder whether the gunicorn is present there or not.  Clearly there is no problem with nginx.