# Failed to start gunicorn.service: Unit gunicorn.service not found. Ubunto 18.04

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, gunicorn, ubuntu-18.04

I am following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04) How To Set Up Django with Postgres, Nginx, and Gunicorn on Ubuntu 18.04 guide.

**I have created the following file .socket**

`sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket`

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

**I have created the following file .service**

`sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service`

**Original RECOMENDED_FORMATTING-s in the [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04)**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target


[Service]
User=sammyRECOMENDED_FORMATTING
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/sammyRECOMENDED_FORMATTING/myprojectdirRECOMENDED_FORMATTING
ExecStart=/home/sammyRECOMENDED_FORMATTING/myprojectdirRECOMENDED_FORMATTING/myprojectenvRECOMENDED_FORMATTING/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          myprojectRECOMENDED_FORMATTING.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**How I have formatted my own version** I had my virtual environment outside of the project folder on the server

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=SERVER_USER
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/SERVER_USER/MAIN_PROJECT_FOLDER
ExecStart=/home/SERVER_USER/ven/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/home/SERVER_USER/MAIN_PROJECT_FOLDER/MAINAPPLICATION_FOLDER.sock \
          MAINAPPLICATION_FOLDER.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**I have also tried leaving these as originally recommended**

`--bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \`

**Than I have tried to execute the following code**

`sudo systemctl start gunicorn`

**error message 1**

`Failed to start gunicorn.service: Unit gunicorn.service not found.`

**and I have also tried with 2**

`sudo systemctl start gunicorn.socket`

**Error message 2**

```
Failed to start gunicorn.socket: Unit gunicorn.socket is not loaded properly: Invalid argument.
See system logs and 'systemctl status gunicorn.socket' for details.
```

**To solve this, I have tried**

- [Failed to start gunicorn.service: Unit gunicorn.service not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40711747/failed-to-start-gunicorn-service-unit-gunicorn-service-not-found) This points back to the exact same guide that I am doing except with an older version of linux.
- this is not the same code and not answered https://askubuntu.com/questions/748836/unit-gunicorn-service-failed-to-load-no-such-file-or-directory
- Run: `systemctl status gunicorn.socket` Result: `Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of gunicorn.socket changed on disk
  ● gunicorn.socket - gunicorn daemon
  Loaded: error (Reason: Invalid argument)
  Active: inactive (dead)`
- Run: `systemctl is-enabled gunicorn.socket` Result: `enabled`
- Run: `systemctl is-enabled gunicorn.service` Result: `Failed to get unit file state for gunicorn.service: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This fixed it:

`sudo systemctl enable gunicorn.service`

Answer (score 5):

It cost me about three hours ... Fxxx

Don't do this:

```
  sudo systemctl start gunicorn.socket
  sudo systemctl enable gunicorn.socket
```

Do this:

```
  sudo systemctl enable gunicorn.socket
  sudo systemctl start gunicorn.socket
```

and:

```
  sudo systemctl status gunicorn.socket
```

**it works fine now** !

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense.