# Failed to start gunicorn.service: Job for gunicorn.socket failed . Ubunto 18.04

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I am following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04) How To Set Up Django with Postgres, Nginx, and Gunicorn on Ubuntu 18.04 guide.

**I have created the following file .socket**

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket



[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

**I have created the following file .service.  How I have formatted my own version**

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service

[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=guilhermenog
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/guilhermenog/projetoagenda
ExecStart=/home/guilhermenog/projetoagenda/venv/bin/gunicorn \
       --access-logfile - \
       --workers 3 \
       --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
       agenda.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Than I have tried to execute the following code**

```
sudo systemctl start gunicorn.socket
```

**And i have recibed this message error**

```
Job for gunicorn.socket failed
See "systemctl status gunicorn.socket" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

**After i tried the recommended code**

```
● gunicorn.socket - gunicorn socket
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead)
Listen: /run/gunicorn.sock (Stream)

Apr 26 18:41:45 projetoagenda systemd[1]: gunicorn.socket: Socket service gunicorn.service not 
loaded, refusing.
Apr 26 18:41:45 projetoagenda systemd[1]: Failed to listen on gunicorn socket.
Apr 26 18:48:41 projetoagenda systemd[1]: gunicorn.socket: Socket service gunicorn.service not 
loaded, refusing.
Apr 26 18:48:41 projetoagenda systemd[1]: Failed to listen on gunicorn socket.
Apr 26 18:52:53 projetoagenda systemd[1]: gunicorn.socket: Socket service gunicorn.service not 
loaded, refusing.
Apr 26 18:52:53 projetoagenda systemd[1]: Failed to listen on gunicorn socket.
Apr 26 18:53:27 projetoagenda systemd[1]: gunicorn.socket: Socket service gunicorn.service not 
loaded, refusing.
Apr 26 18:53:27 projetoagenda systemd[1]: Failed to listen on gunicorn socket.
Apr 26 19:02:09 projetoagenda systemd[1]: gunicorn.socket: Socket service gunicorn.service not 
loaded, refusing.
Apr 26 19:02:09 projetoagenda systemd[1]: Failed to listen on gunicorn socket.
```

**i have followed this sugetions but nothing happen**
[Failed to start gunicorn.service: Unit gunicorn.service not found. Ubunto 18.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60837998/failed-to-start-gunicorn-service-unit-gunicorn-service-not-found-ubunto-18-04)

sorry for this question, it´s my firts time asking help in english.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it was also returning the same error. I managed to fix it for myself so I decided to share what I did, perhaps someone finds it useful too:

Fix: First I ran command: `sudo systemctl enable gunicorn.socket` (it created symlink)
Then I tried running: `sudo systemctl start gunicorn.socket` - but it returned that the job for gunicorn socket failed, however, I ran `sudo systemctl enable gunicorn.socket` again and then `sudo systemctl start gunicorn.socket` and the issue was no more and upon checking status ( command `sudo systemctl status gunicorn.socket`) it finally returned that it is active (listening).