# Changes not reflecting on Flask app with Gunicorn and Nginx?

Tags: nginx, flask, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I'm very new to Digital Ocean and deploying Flask apps, so I followed [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-22-04) and served my first app on there. Everything worked out, but when I try to change any of my files, the changes are not reflecting on the domain.

I tried:

- Restarting Ngnix again with `sudo systemctl restart nginx`. That didn't help.
- And then I tried restarting Gunicorn with `sudo systemctl restart gunicorn`, as some advised, but I get the following error: `Failed to restart gunicorn.service: Unit gunicorn.service not found.` I found an advice to create systemd service file for Gunicorn [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52912818/8030746) (granted, this is for a Django app), but I'm not sure if that's something I should do, considering I followed the official tutorial and it wasn't mentioned anywhere.

Does anyone have any suggestions how I can fix this so that the changes are visible? Thank you!